# Meaning of 'utterly untouched person'

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is an sentence from [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/debauch).

> Patrick looked utterly *untouched* by the previous night’s debauch.

What does *untouched* mean here? Does it mean that the debauch did not change his appearance? But in this case the adverb 'utterly' confuses me, you usually use 'utterly' when a substancial change has taken place. I would use 'virtually'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Untouched in this context means *unaffected*. In other words, the previous night's drinking etc. has had no effect on Patrick.

Utterly is used as an intensifier - he is not just unaffected, he is *completely* unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective *untouched* means not affected in this context.

> [untouched](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/untouched) - *Not affected, changed, or damaged in any way*

The adverb *[utterly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/utterly)* means completely. It emphasizes on he remaining unaffected.

I often use *utterly untouched* to describe a place which is neat and clean.